# HTML Template Designs - Alternatives to Theme Forest

Tags: html, css, website-design, template, theme

I'm looking to build a new corporate website using a ready made HTML theme so that I can focus on the business logic rather than on the presentation.

Any recommendations for websites similar and alternative to [Theme Forset](http://themeforest.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple alternatives that I know of:

- [Template Monster](http://www.templatemonster.com/)
- [Wix](http://www.wix.com/)